# Regex for English and Irish Phone Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I've been looking around the web at various `regex` for phone number validation. There is of course hundreds of different examples as there are hundreds of different formats of phone number out there...

I decided I would write my own for two reasons.

1. I wanted to learn more about regular expressions
2. The ones I came across didn't suit my needs

However, I've a few issues I'm wondering some of you might help me clear up in order to make my regular expression better.

The format of the numbers I'm looking for are as follows:

- Must start with either +353 or +44
- Followed by numbers 0 - 9
- ability to include whitespaces between the numbers

Currently I have this:

```
([+][353]{3})[\d\s]{7,11}|([+][44]{2})[\d\s]{7,11}
```

This enables me to enter in numbers in such formats like:

+353xxxxxxx or +44xxxxxxx

The problem I'm having is that it's counting the whitespace in the `{7,11}` and as a result If someone enters:

+353 xxx xxx xxx It will not validate

I'm trying to find out a way that I can allow spaces between any of my numbers 0 - 9 but to limit the numbers at 11.

So potentially somebody could come along and enter in this number:

+353 12 34 56 78

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Note that `[353]{3}` will match `333`, `555`, `553`, `535`, etc. All-in-all your use of classes suggests you should start by reading a regex tutorial.

Comment: Hi Biffen, I will definitely be reading more tutorials, I'm in the process of doing so atm. Appreciate your comment, helpful to see the flaw in my regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The format of the numbers I'm looking for are as follows:
>
> Must start with either +353 or +44
> Followed by numbers 0 - 9
> ability to include whitespaces between the numbers

This is quite simple:

```
\+(353|44)(\s*\d)+
```

As a refinement, you could require a certain range of digits after the international prefix. For example:

```
^\+(353|44)(\s*\d){9,12}$
```

will match `+44` or `+353` followed by between 9 and 12 digits (with optional spaces). The `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string, so additional characters at the beginning or end of the number will cause the match to fail.

Comment: Well that would allow the person to input an arbitrary amount of digits

Comment: Yes, but I can limit that no problem, I just didn't know how to ignore the whitespaces

Comment: @Javacadabra I'm looking for a UK and Northern Ireland phone number that accepts mobile and landline numbers